How to express an angle between two angle bisectors in interior angles of a convex quadrilateral?
Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, I would like to express the angle between angle bisector of internal and external angles of the opposite vertices in interior angles of $ABCD$.
Here is the drawing I have constructed.

By analyzing the two triangles with a common vertex, which is the intersection point of $BC$ and $AL$, I have concluded that $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\left(\angle BAD + \angle BCD\right)+\angle ABC-90^\circ$.
Is there a better way to express angle $\alpha$, i.e. using less angles or less operations?

Don't opposite angles in a quadrilateral always sum to $180^{\circ}$? So doesn't that make $\alpha = \angle ABC$?

@MPW: Consider a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $\angle DAB=58^\circ$ and $\angle BCD=15^\circ$. These angles does not sum up to $180^\circ$, but $ABCD$ can still be a convex quadrilateral :)

Yikes, I guess that’s only true for quadrilaterals inscribed in a circle — my bad

And that evidently characterizes whether or not the quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle


$\angle LEC = \angle BEA = 180^{\circ} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle B$
$\alpha + 180^{\circ} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle B + \frac{180^{\circ} -\angle C}{2} = 180^{\circ}$ (in $\triangle LEC$)
$\alpha + 180^{\circ} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle B + 90^{\circ} -\frac{\angle C}{2} = 180^{\circ}$
$\alpha + 180^{\circ} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle B - \frac{\angle C}{2} = 90^{\circ}$
$\frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle B}{2}+\frac{\angle C}{2}+\frac{\angle D}{2}=180^{\circ}$ (quadrilateral)
$\alpha + \frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle B}{2}+\frac{\angle C}{2}+\frac{\angle D}{2} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle B  - \frac{\angle C}{2} = 90^{\circ}$
$\alpha= 90^{\circ} - |\frac{\angle B}{2} - \frac{\angle D}{2}|$

$\alpha = 180^{\circ} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle D + \frac{180^{\circ} -\angle C}{2}$
$\alpha = \frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle B}{2}+\frac{\angle C}{2}+\frac{\angle D}{2} - \frac{\angle A}{2} - \angle D + 90^{\circ} -\frac{\angle C}{2}$
$\alpha= 90^{\circ} - |\frac{\angle B}{2} - \frac{\angle D}{2}|$ or $\alpha= 90^{\circ} + |\frac{\angle B}{2} - \frac{\angle D}{2}|$

$$\angle LCE=90°-{\angle C\over2}$$

@Intelligenti pauca : thanks a lot. I edited

The case when $AL$ intersects $CD$ is just the same as your proof, I guess? What about when $AL$ passes through $C$?

@Rusurano : I added the case if bisector of $\angle A$ passes through point $C$.
